# ViewController vs. View

Tags: cocoa, xcode, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder

Trying to wrap my head around the apple design scheme.  I have a UIViewController and the corresponding XIB file that has my main screen in my application.  I want to have a button on this XIB that displays another "form" (this is my disconnect) in the foreground where the user selects from a myriad of choices, then it hides that "form" and goes back to the first one.

I'm completely lost here.  Initially I thought I'd just add another view and set the self.view of my controller to the new view, add another IBAction and call it a day, but I can't seem to make that work.  For sake of argument, say I want to "gray out" the current form, have a modal type window that takes up roughly 60% of the screen and requires you select an option, then it hides itself and we go back to normal.  What is the standard approach here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ViewController does what's its name indicates; controls a UIView. If you have an additional view for your form, you can just add it to the ViewController's view:

```
[self.view addSubview:yourFormUIView];
```

This will add your new view to the view that is (essentially) in the the related .xib file. You might also want to check out [modal view controllers](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html) istead.